# Get latest unique rows from SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this data in my data warehouse with big query.

```
 ID | value |1    latest_metric      
--------+------------------------
 1  |  AA  | 2019-04-30 00:00:00-04
 2  |  AB  | 2019-05-08 00:00:00-04
 2  |  AD  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00-04
 2  |  AC  | 2019-05-09 00:00:00-04
 3  |  BB  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00-04
 3  |  BC  | 2019-05-08 00:00:00-04
```

It saves all inserts and updates in my database, but I need to get the latest unique rows of each for reporting, how can I get this results with SQL big query?

```
 ID | value |1    latest_metric      
--------+------------------------
 1  |  AA  | 2019-04-30 00:00:00-04
 2  |  AC  | 2019-05-09 00:00:00-04
 3  |  BC  | 2019-05-12 00:00:00-04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the following. Also, the results that you've supplied are incorrect (i think) based on your input data. record 3 should have the date `2019-05-08 00:00:00` and not `2019-05-12 00:00:00`

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT (_rownum)
    FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY latest_metric DESC) _rownum,
        value,
        LATEST_METRIC
    FROM simon_d.test_table)
WHERE
  _rownum = 1;
```

Results of above:

```
+--+-----+-----------------------------+
|ID|VALUE|LATEST_METRIC                |
+--+-----+-----------------------------+
|1 |AA   |2019-04-30 00:00:00.000000000|
|2 |AC   |2019-05-09 00:00:00.000000000|
|3 |BC   |2019-05-08 00:00:00.000000000|
+--+-----+-----------------------------+
```

Full reproducible example:

```sql
-- Create sample table
create or replace table simon_d.test_table
(
    id            int64,
    value         string,
    latest_metric timestamp
)
;

-- Insert sample data
insert into simon_d.test_table
values (1, 'AA', '2019-04-30 00:00:00'),
       (2, 'AB', '2019-05-08 00:00:00'),
       (2, 'AD', '2019-05-07 00:00:00'),
       (2, 'AC', '2019-05-09 00:00:00'),
       (3, 'BB', '2019-05-07 00:00:00'),
       (3, 'BC', '2019-05-08 00:00:00')
;

-- Run Query
SELECT * EXCEPT (_rownum)
    FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY latest_metric DESC) _rownum,
        value,
        LATEST_METRIC
    FROM simon_d.test_table)
WHERE
  _rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: No worries. Also, I don't know why this was closed since the answer that is being linked to does not answer this question. I've raised a flag to correct